# Significato e origine dell'espressione "la testa come un cesto"

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

Nel racconto *La radura* di Marisa Madieri (pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto questa frase:

> "Nei giorni piú turbolenti della sua relazione, la zia Augusta faceva a tutti *la testa come un cesto* con le sue disavventure amorose."

Cosa significhi "la testa come un cesto" posso più o meno immaginarlo dal contesto (mi piacerebbe però avere le vostre spiegazioni per esserne più sicura). Comunque, sapreste spiegarmi qual è l'origine di questa curiosa espressione?

Comment: Io non l'ho mai sentito!

Comment: "Atabalar". Credo comunque sia (quantomeno) un regionalismo, e non ne conosco l'origine.

Comment: Altra espressione tipica (colloquiale): "mi ha fatto la testa come un pallone".

Comment: @karoshi: Davvero molto curioso! In catalano sarebbe "el cap com un timbal" o "com un bombo" o "com un tabal", parole che tutte significano "tamburo".

Comment: Ho trovato [qui](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/testa.shtml#27) il significato.

Comment: Ho trovato un'interessante spiegazione nella pagina 72 di questo libro del 1815:  https://books.google.es/books?id=pIrcshzKMfEC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=cestone

Answer (score 9):

Il significato di questa espressione viene spiegato nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/testa.shtml#27):

> **fare la testa come un cestone** ***(raro)***
>
> - **Fig.:** frastornare, rintronare di chiacchiere, di raccomandazioni, di rumore, di confusione o d'idee.
> - **Var.:** *avere il capo come un cestone; fare una testa come un cestone; avere una testa come un cestone.*

L'espressione "avere il capo come un cestone" appare nel poema eroicomico *Il Malmantile Racquistato* del fiorentino Lorenzo Lippi (1606-1665).

Su Google Books si trova un'[edizione del 1815 di questo poema](https://books.google.es/books?id=pIrcshzKMfEC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=cestone#v=onepage&q=cestone&f=false) con interessantissime "note di Puccio Lamoni e d'altri". In una di queste note si legge:

> «IL CAPO ELL'HA COME UN CESTONE. Gli si confonde il cervello. Fa capo grosso. Quando diciamo Fa il capo grosso, o Se gl'ingrossa il capo, intendiamo Se gli confonde il giudizio. E Cestone è un gran Paniere fatto di vinciglie di castagno intessute, ed è capace di mezza soma: e perchè ha la figura del capo dell'uomo, si fa questa comparazione.»

Dunque, il "cestone" era un grande paniere (capace di "mezza soma") fatto di strisce di castagno intessute, con una forma che assomigliava alla testa di una persona. Con questa espressione si voleva evocare l'immagine di una testa che "ingrandiva" perché era tutta piena "di chiacchiere, di raccomandazioni, di rumore, di confusione o d'idee".

Comment: Nel vocabolario Treccani ho trovato che [cesto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cesto2/) ha anche questo significato: «*Complesso delle foglie addensate che, in alcune piante, nascono da un fusto molto breve.*» Essendo i personaggi di *La radura* delle margherite (la zia Augusta stessa è una margherita), penso che forse la scrittrice abbia voluto fare qui un gioco di parole.