# Cosa vuol dire: "fare la testa come una mongolfiera"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Cosa vuol dire la locuzione: "fare la testa come una mongolfiera"?

Comment: Mi sono permesso di modificare il testo della domanda perché un [aforisma](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aforisma) è tutt'altra cosa.

Comment: @DaG Grazie. Allora sarebbe una metafora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La locuzione *fare la testa come una mongolfiera* è simile a [*fare la testa come un pallone*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/testa.shtml#28) (d'altronde la mongolfiera viene chiamata anche pallone (aerostatico), [come riportato da Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mongolfiera_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/))

> • Fig.: frastornare, provocare una fastidiosa sensazione di
>   confusione, detto specialmente di chiacchiere, discorsi,
>   raccomandazioni e così via. Anche lasciare rintronati, stordire con un
>   rumore assordante e simili. Var.: fare la testa come una campana;
>   avere la testa come un pallone; avere la testa come una campana

Significa appunto provocare stordimento e confusione, ad esempio, con un sacco di chiacchere.

Nella stessa pagina viene riportato anche *fare la testa come un cestone*, sebbene sia indicato come raro.

Comment: Domanda correlata: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/significato-e-origine-dellespressione-la-testa-come-un-cesto.